# Sample field update workflow in SharePoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to design a workflow in SharePoint designer which will manually run on all the documents copy Column 1 value to Column 2 with the use of some string function.

Mainly string function will check if Column 1 has any special character like _ or - or / if there then remove it and copy result into Column 2.

For example, Using following workflow I can set existing "Title" field value to new "SurveyName" field but there is no options to add string functions.

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do it in SharePoint Designer without using custom created actions. If you have a constant number of those characters (for example, always 3 underscores and always 5 dashes) then you can use a calculated field with a formula to replace every character you need.


Some of the custom actions to install:
[SharePoint Designer Workflow String Actions](http://spdwfstringactions.codeplex.com/) - Replace

[iLove SharePoint](http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/20898) - Execute SQL